Apache Rewrite Cond for -no- HTTP_USER_AGENT
I'm battling the bots with Apache's RewriteCond/Rewrite Rule.  I see a lot of www_log entries with "-" for the HTTP_USER_AGENT, meaning the user agent was blank
Q1) Is there any legitimate reason for "clients" to NOT send a user agent?
Q2) Is the proper syntax RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ""  or RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "-"
Hmmm.  I'll have to answer my own questions.
A1) I can't imagine any.
A2)
OK, I tested using HTTP_REFERER, and found that ="" is the correct way to match an empty user agent:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ""  [NC]  # WRONG this matches anything

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "=" [NC]  # WRONG this matches only =

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ="" [NC]  # RIGHT this matches an empty string

